# #OPENCL#clBuildProgram failed with error code -5

Tags: opencl, gpu

I met a problem when using clBuildProgram() on GTX 750. The kernel failed to build with error code -5(CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES) and an empty build log.

There is a possible solution, which is adding '-cl-nv-verbose' as input option to clBuildProgram(). However, it doesn't work for all kernels. 
Based on that, I tried another optimization option which is '-cl-opt-disable'. It also works for some kernels.

Then I got confused.

1. I cannot find the real reason for causing the error;
2. Why do different build-options make sense for some kernels?
3. The error seems like architecture independent.Since the same Opencl code is executed successfully on GTX 750, while failed on Tesla P100.

Does anyone has ideas?

Comment: Another issue, I took a simple opencl benchmark - matrix multiplication. Building the kernel without any build options input. Then I wrote a python script to execute it. Using sudo python script.py doesn't make errors, however only using python script would also make the same error mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Possible reasons I can think of:

1. Running out of registers. This happens if you have a lot of (`private`) variables in your kernel code, especially arrays. Each core only has a certain amount of registers available (architecture dependent), and it may not be possible for the compiler to "spill" them to global memory. If this is the problem, you can try to rearrange your code so your variables have more limited scope, or you can try to move some arrays to `local` memory (bearing in mind this is shared between work items in a group, and also limited in size). A good GPU profiler/code analysis tool should be able to tell you how much register pressure there is, so if you've got the kernel working on some hardware, you should be able to find out register pressure for that, and draw conclusions for other hardware too.
2. Code size itself. I didn't think this should be much of a problem anymore on modern GPUs, but it might be possible if you have truly gigantic kernels.

Comment: 2) can still happen on modern GPUs when using some form of templating (having the same kernel over and over with slight differences in the same file)

Comment: Can you recommend me one GPU profiler analysis tool? I would like to test the register pressure.